# Off and of when using moments (of time)

Tags: grammar

When describing a location, I have seen both 'minutes off' as well as 'minutes of'. My understanding is that in the example 'The shop is minutes off the High St', it is being used as a phrasal verb (by way of explanation, if I remove the minutes in the example above, it is obviously NOT a preposition) and so off is correct. Wrong?

Comment: The words "of" and "off" have entirely different meanings. Can you spare a few minutes of your time to add a sentence with "minutes of" that you think is correct?

Comment: You could say the shop is off High Street (assuming “the” is unnecessary) or you could say that the shop is within minutes of High Street.  Either works.  If you say the shop is of of High Street, it suggests it’s one of the shops on the street itself that contribute to its character.

Comment: '"The shop is minutes off the High Street" is an informal way of saying that it is within a few minutes' walk of (or from) the street.

Comment: Please include an example of the use of "_of_" so we can explain the difference. As Mr Lister says, they are different words with completely different meanings.

Comment: You're making the false assumption that this is a phrasal verb. (And that every phrasal verb has a preposition.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you must be mistaken. "Of" could not be used instead of "off" in this context, and even your example sentence using "off" seems wrong.

When giving directions we do use "off" to describe a turn from one street to another, for example:

> The shop is on the third road off the high street.

When talking about time or distance in relation to a particular place, we use "*from*":

> The shop is 6 minutes from my house.
>   The shop is 2 miles from the city centre

I suppose it is possible you heard someone say "x minutes off the high street", as it is one thing to get perfect grammar in writing and another to speak it extemporaneously. You could have misheard that as "of".